# Dissolved gas release from liquid

Tags: experimental-physics

I wish I could directly embed this video here

https://youtu.be/Syb3MHtjojQ

It can be seen that no external chemical has be put into the bottle, so the bottle content has clearly not been modified.

A friend of mine said it must be capillary action, but it doesn't look like it one to me.

It's doesn't look normal CO<sub>2</sub> release either, since it flows steadily for 40+ seconds.

Assuming no battery/pump has been attached to the straw, how can this be explained scientifically?

Comment: Please add a few relevant screenshots

Comment: "*It's doesn't look normal CO2 release either, since it flows steadily for 40+ seconds*" Your soda takes many minutes to go flat and is not normally sealed with only a tiny straw as the outlet. Release the pressure on a plastic soda bottle and reseal it. The bottle gets pressurized and firm again.

Comment: @huenma, the title of your question should tell the reader what the question is about. Can you [edit] it so that if it showed up in search results the reader might know?

Comment: you used the `experimental-physics` tag ... did you actually perform an experiment to determine the cause of the fountain effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen similar action when a straw is in a glass of soda.  Bubbles form on the straw, causing it to "float" upwards, then the bubbles break free and the straw sinks again. Rinse, lather, repeat.

In both scenarios what we're seeing is the slow release of CO<sub>2</sub> from dissolved to gas-bubble phase.   Similarly, opening a bottle of soda doesn't cause all the dissolved CO<sub>2</sub> to release immediately. You can enjoy the drink for a couple hours (other then temperature change) before all the fizz is lost.

Answer (score 2):

It is CO<sub>2</sub> that is released from the liquid.  As the liquid warms up, it is unable to hold as much of the CO<sub>2</sub> in a dissolved state.  The CO<sub>2</sub> raises the gas pressure above the liquid.  I think that you can figure out the rest.